# Why gcc inserts 'lib' at the beginning of the library files(*.a) in the new Qt version (Qt5.3)

Tags: c++, qt, gcc

With porting my application into Qt5.3 now the gcc compiler inserts 'lib' at the beginning of the library files (*.a). How can I prevent this?
Previously I was working with Qt5.2 and there wasn't such this issue.
How can I fix that? Is that make any problem during linking the library?
(Win7, Qt5.3 gcc)

Comment: The GNU linker have *always* looked for libraries with a `lib` prefix. For example, if you have a library X that you link with `-lX` then the GNU linker will look for a library *file* names `libX.a` or `libX.so`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg So it means that it will not make any troubles for me? even in the windows?

Comment: No, the GNU linker should be able to find the correct files as long as they're in the library search path.